# php round time, keep string format

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

I'm rounding time to one minute using:

```
$mytime = mdate("H:i:s", $time_in_seconds);   

$rounded_time = date('H:i:s', round(strtotime($mytime)/60)*60);
```

The output is for example: `01:09:00` from not rounded `01:08:34`.

How can use the code but keep the seconds format rather than change to date?

Comment: what does `$mytime` look like originally?

Comment: Why don't you just remove `s` from the format if you don't want to show seconds?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @ Galen, for example, `$mytime` looks like `01:08:34` using `gmdate("H:i:s", $time_in_seconds);`

Comment: @lanzz, question edited for better understanding hopefully

Comment: @MikeB, yes but I still need to get a string in seconds format

Comment: @CyberJunkie It is still not clear what the problem is with your current solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using

```
$rounded_time = date('H:i:0');
```

?

Comment: Thanks, that is a solution but in the future I might round it to a different integer

Comment: $myint = 0;
$round = date("H:i:$myint");

Comment: @micheal zelensky, the reason I'm rounding seconds is to also change the minutes or hour should seconds or minutes be at `59`. I'm rounding the entire date to one minute or maybe 15 minutes in the future